# Building a tab separated row

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

The tsv file I work with has 100 columns of which I need only 10 columns.

My task is to open the file, read one row at a time and build another tsv row with only 10 columns. I know the indexes of the columns I need.

```
with open(self.file_name, 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
         trim_row.append(str(row[0]) + "\t" +  str(row[1]) + "\t" + 
         str(row[2]) + "\t" + str(row[4]) + "\t" + str(row[11]))
```

However this is what I see

input row:

```
['2019-01-13', '123'    , 'test',   '123',  '123',  'test', '123',  '123',  '3',    'abc',  'abc',  'def',  '23',   '45',   '40',   '7',    '8',    'a' , '56']
```

What I get is
trim_row:

```
['2019-01-13\t123\ttest\t123\t123']
```

What I need is a subset of columns like this:

```
['2019-01-13', '123'    , 'test',   '123']
```

Comment: Your example output is comma separated, not tab separated. Which do you need? When confirmed, I will update my answer below

Comment: its tab seperated. I was wondering if there's a way to do it without having to write to an output file.

Comment: Well, your "trim_row" above is a tab separated list and should give you what you want then? Try `print(trim_row)` and you should see the values separated by a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use `csv.writer` to more easily take advantage of the standard library. The example code below expects the self.out_file_name to be added to your method:

```
with open(self.file_name, 'r') as input_file and open(self.out_file_name, 'w') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[4], row[11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending all the columns in one string to `input_row`, not an array. Either append one by one, or put them in a list and extend.